# Convert Grayscale to RGB

Tags: arrays, c, buffer

My problem is: I have a picture in my buffer `buffer = (unsigned short *) malloc(imageSize*2);`

This picture is 8 bit per pixel and 1 byte per pixel, so it is a Grayscale picture.

But to display it I need an RGB picture. Because only an RGB picture is supported.
[image: Example]

So I need to change the picture from:

```
index     |  1    |  2    |...
grayvalue |  128  |  135  |...
```

to

```
index     |  1            |  2            |...
grayvalue |  128,128,128  |  135,135,135  |...
```

for | r,g,b |.

My idea is to make an array from the buffer `array[grayvalue] = buffer[count]`, somehow add 2 grayvalues to the same pixel and change the array back into a buffer. But I can´t find how to get an array from a buffer and how to add the grayvalues to 1 pixel. I hope someone has an idea what I mean and can link me to information that I overlooked.

Edit:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long int imageSize = 0;
    unsigned short *buffer = NULL;

    const int Width = 1936, Height = 1460;

    /*code to take raw image data from camera*/


   // Put raw image data from the camera in the buffer.     
      buffer = (unsigned short *) malloc(imageSize*2);


    // GTK

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget* image;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((unsigned short *) buffer, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE, 8,
               Width, Height, Width*1, NULL, NULL);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Image Viewer");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program I use to Display my Image. The Code that I use to take a picture with the camera can´t be shared.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why do you want to add multiple grayvalues? From your description, you just need to write one RGB triple per pixel and only take into account that one pixel. BTW: Your title indicates the opposite direction of conversion.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show how your image is stored.

Comment: I want to add multiple grayvalues so that my 1 Byte per pixel (original picture) will be a 3 Byte per pixel picture. As it is shown in the image of my post Gtk shows my 1 Byte per pixel picture 3 times, that tells me I gave Gtk not enough input.

Comment: What is size and what does `buffer` contain? You can add sample data for a tiny image. If `buffer` is the result of your camera taking a picture with 1byte/pixel then where is the part where you try to convert to 3 bytes/pixel?

Comment: @Gerhardh there is no part where i try to convert to 3 bytes/pixel because i don´t know how. I tryed to look it up online but i didn´t find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code hase 1 main problem:
You create the `pixbuf` with wrong `rowstride` value. It is in bytes, not in pixels. For RGB pixels you need 3 bytes.

After this is fixed you need to convert your greyscale pixels to RGBB pixels. This is not "combining pixels" but simply repeating the same value.

This is some sample code to convert 8bit greyscale to 24bit RGB pixels:

```c
// build:
// gcc -o test `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t r;
  uint8_t g;
  uint8_t b;
} rgb;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t Width  = 1936;
    size_t Height = 1280;
    size_t Stride_8 = Width;   // Might need rounding up
    size_t Stride_rgb = Width; // Might need rounding up

    //Due to lack of camera data, lets use some dummy data...
    uint8_t *buffer_8 = malloc(Stride_8*Height);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      for (size_t y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        buffer_8[Stride_8*y + x] = (x+y) & 0xFF;

    /*code to take raw image data from camera*/

    // Put greyscale image data from the camera into the RGB buffer.     
    rgb *buffer_rgb = malloc(Stride_rgb * Height * sizeof(rgb));
    for (size_t x = 0; x < Width; x++)
      for (size_t y = 0; y < Height; y++)
      {
        // Convert 1 byte greyscale in 3 byte RGB:
        uint8_t grey = buffer_8[Stride_8*y + x];
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].r = grey;
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].g = grey;
        buffer_rgb[Stride_rgb*y + x].b = grey;
        }

    // GTK
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_rgb = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)buffer_rgb, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE, 8,
               Width, Height, Stride_rgb*3, NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf_rgb);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    free(buffer_rgb);
    free(buffer_8);
    return 0;
}
```